# how to read multiple csv files in a directory through python csv() function?

Tags: python, csv

In one of my directory, I have multiple CSV files. I wanted to read the content of all the CSV file through a python code and print the data but till now I am not able to do so.

All the CSV files have the same number of columns and the same column names as well.

I know a way to list all the CSV files in the directory and iterate over them through "os" module and "for" loop.

```
for files in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\AmiteshSahay\\Desktop\\test_csv"):
```

Now use the "csv" module to read the files name

```
reader = csv.reader(files)
```

till here I expect the output to be the names of the CSV files. which happens to be sorted. for example, names are 1.csv, 2.csv so on. But the output is as below

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x0000019F97E0E730>
<_csv.reader object at 0x0000019F97E0E528>
<_csv.reader object at 0x0000019F97E0E730>
<_csv.reader object at 0x0000019F97E0E528>
<_csv.reader object at 0x0000019F97E0E730>
<_csv.reader object at 0x0000019F97E0E528>
```

if I add next() function after the csv.reader(), I get below output

```
['1']
['2']
['3']
['4']
['5']
['6']
```

This happens to be the initials of my CSV files name. Which is partially correct but not fully.

Apart from this once I have the files iterated, how to see the contents of the CSV files on the screen? Today I have 6 files. Later on, I could have 100 files. So, it's not possible to use the file handling method in my scenario.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend reading your CSVs using the pandas library.
Check this answer here: [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Although you asked for python in general, pandas does a great job at data I/O and would help you here in my opinion.

Comment: In the example from your link has "list_ = []", what does "list_". Please share some web link for further study on this part. The example in your web link works as desired.

Comment: @skill_seeker `list_` is a temporary variable holding the list of each read CSV in its own dataframe. If you then want to concatenate them you do `pd.concat(list_)`, but if you're just interested in the individual dataframes, you can look at them individually doing `list_[0]` for example

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I found during developing my project is by using dataframe, read_csv, and glob.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_name = 'train_dataset'
file_type = 'csv'
seperator =','
dataframe = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=seperator) for f in glob.glob(folder_name + "/*."+file_type)],ignore_index=True)
```

Here, all the csv files are loaded into 1 big dataframe.

[image: Project Folder structure]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to import your files as separate dataframes, you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filenames = os.listdir("../data/") # lists all csv files in your directory

def extract_name_files(text): # removes .csv from the name of each file
    name_file = text.strip('.csv').lower()
    return name_file

names_of_files = list(map(extract_name_files,filenames)) # creates a list that will be used to name your dataframes

for i in range(0,len(names_of_files)): # saves each csv in a dataframe structure
    exec(names_of_files[i] + " =  pd.read_csv('../data/'+filenames[i])")
```

Answer (score 1):

> till here I expect the output to be the names of the CSV files

This is the problem. `csv.reader` objects do not represent filenames. They represent **lazy objects** which may be iterated to yield rows from a CSV file. Or, if you wish to print the *entire* CSV file, you can call `list` on the `csv.reader` object:

```
for files in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\AmiteshSahay\\Desktop\\test_csv"):
    reader = csv.reader(files)
    print(list(reader))
```

> if I add next() function after the csv.reader(), I get below output

Yes, this is what you should expect. Calling `next` on an iterator will give you the next value which comes out of that iterator. This would be the first line of each file. For example:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

some_file = StringIO("""1
2
3""")

with some_file as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    print(next(reader))

['1']
```

> which happens to be sorted. for example, names are 1.csv, 2.csv so on.

This is either a coincidence or a correlation between the filename and the contents of the respective file. Calling `next(reader)` will not output part of a filename.

> Apart from this once I have the files iterated, how to see the
>   contents of the csv files on the screen?

Use the `print` command, as in the examples above.

> Today I have 6 files. Later on, I could have 100 files. So, it's not
>   possible to use the file handling method in my scenario.

This is not true. You can define a function to print all or part or your csv file. Then call that function in a `for` loop with filename as an input.

Answer (score 1):

You can read and store several dataframes into separate variables using two lines of code.

```
import pandas as pd

datasets_list = ['users', 'calls', 'messages', 'internet', 'plans']

users, calls, messages, internet, plans = [(pd.read_csv(f'datasets/{dataset_name}.csv')) for dataset_name in datasets_list]
```